# How to enable the option "edit physics shape" in the Sprite Editor?

Tags: unity, tilemap, collider

I can successfully import `.png` files, create tilesets, and use them in my tilemaps in Unity.
Thanks to [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory), I just learned that there exists an option to customize the `Tilemap Collider 2D` in the `Sprite Editor`, which allows me to [set a custom collider for every tile](https://www.aetherpoint.com/blogpost/editing-the-unity-tilemap-collider-2d-box/) instead of going through them one by one.

The steps I follow while creating a tileset in Unity is as follows.

1. Import the `.png` file.
2. Open the Sprite Editor.
3. Select the option `Multiple` for `Sprite Mode`.
4. Select `Slice` from the Sprite Editor.

Then, I create a `Tile Palette` in a folder, drop and drag my created tiles, and start creating my level.

I have never encountered the option to modify the colliders tile by tile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular guide is a few years old. In recent Unity versions, this button has been renamed, but it's still in the same place:

1. Select your spritesheet texture
2. Open the Sprite Editor
3. Click the drop-down labelled "Sprite Editor" in the top-left of the window
4. Choose "Custom Physics Shape" from the drop-down menu

[image: Screenshot showing Custom Physics Shape in Sprite Editor]

[You can read more about how to use this feature in the Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPhysicsShape.html).